# AWS CodeBuild pipeline CodeCommit git repo path

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration

If I configure a CodeBuild pipleline as using the CodeCommit Source provider, what is the path of the source code (git repo) to refer to in the buildspec.yml commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the predefined environment variable "CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR". Details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html